# Python: convert datetime format to another

Tags: python, datetime

So i have this kind f format:

```
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'

date_time = datetime.now()
```

**Ouput**

```
'2019-04-15 07:52:14.211697'
```

And i want to change is into this format: `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f'`

This is what i have try:

```
time = datetime.strptime(str(date_time), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f')
```

And this is the `error`:

> ValueError: time data '2019-04-15 07:52:14.211697' does not match
>   format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f'

**Edit**

So i have this `string`:

```
    maches = regex.findall(
        '[0-9]{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) (?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9]',
        line)

match[0] = '2019-03-13 17:35:35,855'
```

And i want to convert it to `Datetime`:

```
time = datetime.strptime(maches[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f')
```

And this returned another `format`:

```
2019-03-13 17:35:35.855000
```

Why ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use strftime:

```
str_time = datetime.strftime(date_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f')
```

A quick comparison of [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) and [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

> strftime() is used to convert a datetime object to a string
>
> strptime() is used to convert a date string to a datetime object

Also here's a good resource in the documentation describing the differences: [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

**Response to Question Edit**

In response to your edit strptime takes a string date and converts it into a datetime object. The format you pass to it just tells it how to parse the string to datetime. It **does not** dictate it's print format. You are calling print on a datetime object in this case so the output is dictated by the `__str__` method on the datetime object.

If you want to print it in a certain way pass it to strftime with the format you want to output it as:

```
obj_time = datetime.strptime(maches[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f')
print(datetime.strftime(obj_time , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f'))
```

Comment: Can i have simple code example ? i did not understand what i did wrong

Comment: Your `maches[0]` is already in the string format you want. You don't need to pass it to `strptime`.

Comment: TypeError: strptime() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: i dont want to print but return datetime object with this format

Comment: @falukky this isn't possible. We cannot store the output format we want in the datetime object. You will need to call strftime on your datetime object to get your string output. Or use @Arunkumar answer to format the string you desire from the datetime object: `'{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f}'.format(date_time)`

Answer (score 1):

Use strftime.

```
date_time = datetime.now()
print(date_time)
print(datetime.strftime(date_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f'))

2019-04-15 10:26:08.637630
2019-04-15 10:26:08,637630
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this you get this format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f'

```
print '{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f}'.format(date_time)
```